# Different theme styles for not all views

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

In my Android app I have two different themes (light and dark).
For example:

```
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

So, now I can apply, for example, different text colors to a TextView (white for dark theme and black for light):

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewDark</item>

<style name="TextViewDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

But it will apply to **all** TextViews.

The main question, is it possible to make in XML (not programmatically) next:

Light theme: Half of TextViews text color black, and another half green.
Black theme: TextViews that black in Light theme - red, and another half - blue (which are green in Light theme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 classes extends TextView

```
public class OneTextView extends TextView {

    public OneTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public OneTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public OneTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        int[] attrs = new int[] { R.attr.myFirstColor}; 
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs); 
        int appColor = ta.getColor(0, 0); 
        ta.recycle();

        // set theme color
        setTextColor(appColor);
    }
}

public class SecondTextView extends TextView {

    public SecondTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public SecondTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public SecondTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        int[] attrs = new int[] { R.attr.mySecondColor}; 
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs); 
        int appColor = ta.getColor(0, 0); 
        ta.recycle();

        // set theme color
        setTextColor(appColor);
    }
}
```

each class you can use in xml like this

```
<com.route.to.class.OneTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

OneTextView can have black and red colors

SecondTextView can have green and blue colors

define `attr.xml` in `values`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myFirstColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="mySecondColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

Then in your `styles.xml`, define colors for each theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Light">
   <item name="myFirstColor">@color/black</item>
   <item name="mySecondColor">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.Dark">
   <item name="myFirstColor">@color/green</item>
   <item name="mySecondColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that it is possible to create its own attributes. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="TextViewDark">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewLight">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

then you can use it in `main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/light_text_view"
        android:text"i´m use light theme"
        style="@style/TextViewLight"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dark_text_view"
        android:text"i´m use darktheme"
        style="@style/TextViewDark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

you don´t need to define styles in `AppThemes`

Comment: Not fully understood. Can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: But, in this case, when i switch my app theme from light to dark, TextView's styles still the same, right? First TV will have color accent and second one green color. And they will not depends on theme wich i choose(light or dark).